# Removing navigation bar in responsive website layout

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to remove a navigation bar on the mobile site for my website. however, the `display: none;` doesn't seem to do anything.
I am not sure if the javascript I have used is affecting this as I can't stop the javascript from running at the screen width breakpoint.
to remove the elements in javaScript, I tried using `screen.width`

I have linked the code below:

```js
// When the user scrolls down 50px from the top of the document, resize the header's font size window.onscroll = function() {scrollFunction()};
function scrollFunction() {
    if (document.body.scrollTop > 30 || document.documentElement.scrollTop > 30) {
        document.getElementById("navbar").style.fontSize = "30px";
        document.getElementById("logo").style.width = "100px";
        document.getElementById("nav").style.paddingTop = "20px";
    
} else {
    document.getElementById("navbar").style.fontSize = "90px";
    document.getElementById("logo").style.width = "200px";
    document.getElementById("nav").style.paddingTop = "100px";
    document.getElementById("navbar").style.backgroundColor = 'green' ;

}
}
```

```css
li a{
color: black;
}

li a:visited{
    color: black;}

li a:hover{
    color: #cebea1;}

/*for Desktop*/
@media only screen and (min-width: 600px) { 
    .mobileNav{display: none;}

    #navbar {
  background-color: white;
  padding-top: 25px;
  color: black;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 90px; 
  font-weight: bold;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  transition: 1s ease-in-out;
}


.nav{
    font-size: 20px; 
    border-width:1px 0;
    list-style:none;
    margin:0;
    text-align:center;
}
.nav li{
    display:inline;
}
.nav a{
    display:inline-block;
    padding:10px;
    padding-right: 20px;
    padding-top: 45px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 15px;
    font-family: 'Quicksand', sans-serif;

}

#logo{
    padding-left: 10px;
    height: auto;
    width: 200px;
    transition: 1s ease-in-out;
}


#navSpace{
    margin-top:260px;
    content: '.';
    visibility: hidden;
}

/*For Mobile*/
@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
    #navbar{display: none;}
    .nav{display: none;}
    .nav li{display: none;}
    .nav a{display: none;}
    #logo{display: none;}

    #navSpace{
    margin-top:0px;
    content: '';}
    .mobileNav li {
    float: left;
  }
  .mobileNav li a {
    padding: 20px 30px;
  }
  .mobileNav .menu {
    clear: none;
    float: right;
    max-height: none;
  }
  .mobileNav .menu-icon {
  display: none;
  }
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>home</title>
    <meta meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, user-scalable=no" />
    <link href="css/normalize.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <link href="css/navbar.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <link href="css/about.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Merienda+One&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="js/navbar.js"></script>
</head>
<!--navigation bar-->
<!--    desktop version-->
    <div id="navbar">
        <a href="page.html"><img id="logo" src="images/logoBlack.png"></a>
<ul class="nav">
  <li><a href="/">About</a></li>
  <li><a href="/work/">Work</a></li>
  <li><a href="/media.html">Media</a></li>
  <li><a href="/contact">Contact</a></li>
</ul></div>

<!--movile version-->
    <header class="mobileNav">
  <a href="" class="logo">CSS Nav</a>
  <input class="menu-btn" type="checkbox" id="menu-btn" />
  <label class="menu-icon" for="menu-btn"><span class="navicon"></span></label>
  <ul class="menu">
    <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
    <li><a href="#work">Work</a></li>
    <li><a href="#media">Media</a></li>
    <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
  </ul>
</header>

<!--    space under desktop nevigation bar-->
<div id="navSpace"></div>
<!--    end of navigation bar-->
<body>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: can you put snippet of the code

Answer (score 1):

Your HTML structure is not between the `<body>` tags.
Also there is a "}" missing on #navbar.

```
/*for Desktop*/
@media only screen and (min-width: 600px) { 
   ...
  #navbar {
    background-color: white;
    ...
    transition: 1s ease-in-out;
  } <- missing

}
```

Comment: The start and end tags for the body element are optional.

Answer (score 0):

'all nested css Inside `@media screen and (min-width: 600px)` will only going to fire if `width < 600px`. And that's what makes your another media queries which is `@media only screen and (max-width: 600px)` nested inside of it will never going to fire.

**mobile first design** is which I think the most easiest way to solve this problem.

CSS code:

```
li a {
  color: black;
}

li a:visited {
  color: black;
}

li a:hover {
  color: #cebea1;
}

#navbar {
  display: none;
}

#navSpace {
  margin-top: 0px;
  content: "";
}
.mobileNav li {
  float: left;
}
.mobileNav li a {
  padding: 20px 30px;
}
.mobileNav .menu {
  clear: none;
  float: right;
  max-height: none;
}
.mobileNav .menu-icon {
  display: none;
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 600px) {
  .mobileNav {
    display: none;
  }

  #navbar {
    background-color: white;
    padding-top: 25px;
    color: black;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 90px;
    font-weight: bold;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    transition: 1s ease-in-out;
    display: block;
  }

  .nav {
    font-size: 20px;
    border-width: 1px 0;
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    text-align: center;
  }
  .nav li {
    display: inline;
  }
  .nav a {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 10px;
    padding-right: 20px;
    padding-top: 45px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 15px;
    font-family: "Quicksand", sans-serif;
  }

  #logo {
    padding-left: 10px;
    height: auto;
    width: 200px;
    transition: 1s ease-in-out;
  }

  #navSpace {
    margin-top: 260px;
    content: ".";
    visibility: hidden;
  }
}
```

check codesandbox for demo:

https://codesandbox.io/s/jovial-sea-ojwee?file=/style.css:0-1265